# How to give validations as input to Custom Form Element

Tags: angular, forms

I wish to give some validations to my custom input template from app.component.html, How can we achieve this? Please find below the code base to repoduce. I wish to give input validations from app.component.html to 'app-custom-form-control' custom template, and use the input validations

Parent Form Component or App Component

```
import {
    Component
}
from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    Validators,
    AbstractControl
}
from '@angular/forms';

 @ Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    form: FormGroup;
    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
                first: '',
                last: '',
                salary: ''

            })
    }
    customValidator(c: AbstractControl) {
        return c.get('password').value ===
        c.get('repassword').value
         ? null : {
            'nomatch': true
        }
    }
}
```

Parent HTML or App Template HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="first">
    <input formControlName="last">
    <app-custom-form-control formControlName="salary">
    </app-custom-form-control> 
</form>
{{ form.value | json}}
{{ form.status }}
```

Custom Template HTML - Custom Input field

```
<input type="text" #input (input)="onChange($event.target.value)" 
                   (blur)="onTouched()" [disabled]="disabled" >

<div class='error' *ngIf="controlDir && 
                      !controlDir.control.valid">
                  This fields is invalid
```

Custom Component

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    ViewChild,
    ElementRef,
    Self,
    Input
}
from '@angular/core';
import {
    ControlValueAccessor,
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    NG_VALIDATORS,
    Validators,
    AbstractControl,
    NgControl
}
from '@angular/forms';
 @ Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-form-control',
    templateUrl: './custom-form-control.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./custom-form-control.component.css'],

})
export class CustomFormControlComponent implements OnInit,
ControlValueAccessor {
     @ ViewChild('input')input: ElementRef
    onChange: (value: any) => void;
    onTouched: () => void;
    disabled: boolean;
    constructor( @ Self()public controlDir: NgControl) {
        controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        const control = this.controlDir.control;
        let validators = control.validator ? [control.validator,
                Validators.required] : Validators.required;
        control.setValidators(validators);
        control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    writeValue(value: any) { // model to view change reflect handler
        this.input.nativeElement.value = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    // optional
    setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    // validate(ctrl: AbstractControl) {
    //   return Validators.required(ctrl);
    // }

}
```

End of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `setValidators` on the parent form and accessed the same from a custom element through the controls validator.